# How to get the MAX row with a GROUP BY?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an SQL table that is build up like so:

Items:

```
Id         ItemId     VersionId
---------- ---------- ----------
1          1          1
2          1          2
3          1          3
4          2          1
5          2          2
6          3          1
```

Now I would like to use linq select the latest version of each item. The expected output would be:

```
Id         ItemId     VersionId
---------- ---------- ----------
3          1          3
5          2          2
6          3          1
```

Each item has their own version count, so making a new version of Item 1 would give it VersionId 4, while making a new version of Item 3 will give it a VersionId of 2.

So far I've attempted to select the items, then use a GroupBy:

```
var query = from i in items
            select i;

var test = query.GroupBy(q => q.ItemId).ToList();
```

This returns a list of 3 groups, one group for each item.

Now how would I continue and get a list of only the items of the latest version from these groups?

Comment: `var test = query.GroupBy(q => q.ItemId).Select(chunk => chunk.OrderByDescending(item => item.VersionId).First()).ToList();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the highest version, you can order each group and only take the top version after ordering:

```
var test = query.GroupBy(q => q.ItemId)
                .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(g => g.VersionId).First())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This syntax gives the following error: "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead." - Changing this to FirstOrDefault or splitting the query fixes it.

Comment: @Patrick, yes, it's a linq to entities limitation (would work fine with linq to object for instance)

Comment: @Patrick Well, that depends on the datasource. This query will work for Linq-To-Objects, if your datasource needs special constraints, make sure you meet them.

Comment: please, correct me if I wrong, but isn't it better to `OrderByDescending` right before `GroupBy`?

Comment: @vasily.sib The requirement was to order *each group* by version. Ordering before grouping *might* work on certain datasources, but is not guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for comment, but could you please provide a sample where it might not work? As far, as I can test it always work:\

Comment: @vasily.sib To be honest, I don't have the time to look for an example. All I know is that my code is guaranteed behavior, putting the order before the group is not guaranteed to work. It is in Linq-To-Objects, but as soon as the datasource interprets your expression tree, in my case there's no way to interpret it differently while in yours you need to be lucky and the datasource has to have the ability to preserve order while grouping. Some guarantee that, others don't.

Comment: @nvoigt I agree with your solution, it guarantee to work, no doubt. But this N ordering operation disturb my inner perfectionist:) I'm just wondering is there any other solution? Ideally with some sort of `GroupByMax` or similar.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.